# Websocket message logging

Tags: nginx, logging, websocket, proxy, haproxy

I have some websocket clients connected to my backend application and I currently log the incoming and outgoing WS frames within my application for debugging purposes. The messages do not contain any sensitive data.

The websocket server is just one part of my application and when there are a lot clients sending and receiving data, logging the frames becomes expensive, so I would like to move this out of my application.

Is there anything I can use to log the websocket messages? Maybe a webserver (NGINX, HAProxy, Apache, ...) that supports this out of the box? Or is there an application I can put in between the webserver and the backend application that acts as a proxy and additionally logs the messages?

1. Client -> Webserver -> Proxy (+ Logging) -> Application
2. Client -> Webserver (+ Logging) -> Application
3. ...